# SQL [SSMS]: How to return one or the other value, but not both

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a column with one of two values, 'A' or 'I'. I want to always return 'I', but not if 'A' exists, in which case, return 'A'.

Example Table:

```
Name   | Active?
----------------
Steve  |   A
Steve  |   I
Steve  |   I
Andrew |   I
Mark   |   A
Mark   |   I
Carl   |   I
Carl   |   I
```

Example Results:

```
Name   | Active?
----------------
Steve  |   A
Andrew |   I
Mark   |   A
Carl   |   I
Carl   |   I
```

Notice that [name] 'Carl' has two 'I' values in the [Active?] field, so it returns both instances. [name] Steve also has two 'I' values, but also an 'A' value, so the 'I's are ignored and the 'A' is returned.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.active = 'A' or
      (t.active = 'I' and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.name = t.name and t2.active = 'A'
                  );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when active = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) as num_a
      from t
     ) t
where (active = 'A' and num_a > 00 or
      num_a = 0;
```

Comment: Wow, quick and effective response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The exact way is using

> not exists

select t.* from t where t.active = 'A' or       (t.active = 'I' and        not exists (select 1                    from t t2                    where t2.name = t.name and t2.active = 'A'                   );

Answer (score 0):

More set aproach:

```
SELECT t.Name, ISNULL(A."Active?", I."Active?") AS "Active?"
FROM "Example Table" AS t
LEFT JOIN "Example Table" AS A
  ON t.Name = A.Name AND A."Active?" = 'A'
LEFT JOIN "Example Table" AS I
  ON t.Name = I.Name AND I."Active?" <> 'A'
GROUP BY t.Name, A.Name, A."Active?", I.Name, I."Active?"
```